# Mongodb 3.0.1 in ubuntu starts but status, stop or restart show 'mongo stop/waiting'

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am relatively new to Mongo and have installed 3.0.1 on a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). The database starts without problems but I am unable to 'sudo service mongod [stop/restart/status]' using the default apt-get installation. The process shows up in ps but status shows 'mongod stop/waiting'. Has anyone seen this before?

Just to clarify, the process is running fine but I am unable to use sudo service to check the status, stop, or restart the process. Currently, I am shutting mongo down manually from mongo shell. Here is a startup log

```
2015-03-30T08:25:31.066Z I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2015-03-30T08:25:31.080Z I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2015-03-30T08:25:31.163Z I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6266 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb_wtiger 64-bit host=my.hostname.com
2015-03-30T08:25:31.164Z I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.1
2015-03-30T08:25:31.164Z I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 534b5a3f9d10f00cd27737fbcd951032248b5952
2015-03-30T08:25:31.164Z I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2015-03-30T08:25:31.164Z I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-167-176-91 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-03-30T08:25:31.164Z I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-03-30T08:25:31.164Z I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017, unixDomainSocket: { enabled: true }, wireObjectCheck: false }, processManagement: { fork: true }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb_wtiger", directoryPerDB: true, engine: "wiredTiger", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", timeStampFormat: "iso8601-utc" } }
2015-03-30T08:25:31.238Z I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Comment: can you share the mongo logs after you issue the service stop

Comment: Please share the logs for the mongod process. It usually has the details of the error which caused the mongod to stop

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but the process starts just fine. mongod doesn't stop and there are no errors in the log. I'm just unable to use sudo service stop or restart. I have to go into the mongo shell to shut the server down.